# Hide link navigation customer account on specific condition

Tags: magento2, customer-account, condition

I'm would like to know if it's possible to hide a navigation link of the Customer Account dashboard depending on a condition.

For example, I would like to display this block only if customer has a specific account:

[image]

Is it possible ? Does anyone can help me ?

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0):

The image you posted is how you add a new link. That interface only have 1 method, which is not related to render

So you can go up to one level, check the parent to see how it renders the child blocks.
This is the parent block `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation` and it has the `getLinks` method which in the body function, it will get the child blocks (the blocks that you added via layout).

You can start investigating from this method